# Determine the type of a generic class at Runtime

Tags: java, generics, if-statement

I am aware of the fact that the site is fraught with similar questions and that by a quick reading of the given question the first answer coming to mind is "No, you can 't", but I still have the impression that what I am asking is not impossible by any means.

I have created a generic method in a class and I want to get check the type of the Object passed to the method. I know that it cannot be done directly, hence I pass an object `Class<T>` obj to the method. However I cannot find the way to perform properly the type-checking in the method body.

```
public <T> void readData(T obj1, Class<T> obj2){
}
```

Assuming that `T` is always of one of three types: `ClassA`, `ClassB` or `ClassC`. How should the if-else-if block look like?

Comment: I guess the worst would be `if (obj1 instanceof ClassA) { ... } if (obj1 instanceof ClassB) { ...} ....`

Comment: you can always do the obj1.getClass().getSimpleName().equals(same for obj2) and thus knowing if they are equal in name, otherwise i dont see why sending *two* parameters.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza is right.  In that case you don't even need obj2.

Comment: You reduced your actual problem to an abstract question. However, what's left is not enough to understand -- and thus solve -- your original problem. What object, what class? From what I see you have an instance of `T` and want to re-assert that it is an instance of `T`. That's superfluous.

Comment: I agree with @BenSchulz. We need more information on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, it would be bad design using `intanceof`, why use a generic method at all then?

Comment: @RudolphEst based on the stated problem, there's no other solution AFAIK. Another (and better) solution could be that `ClassA` and the others implements the same interface and OP could use `<T extends TheInterface>`, but as said by you two, this can't be conceived with the actual problem description.

Comment: @Infested, I understand your meaning, but class objects allow a simpler method. `obj2.isInstance(obj1)` would return true if `obj1` is an instance of `obj2` class. Though this still isn't useful, because `obj1` is _always_ an instance of `obj2` class according to the definition of the generic method.

Comment: @RudolphEst I wasnt sure if java allows for each T be its own, thats why i suggested this approach. Also glad to learn a new thing! thx.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`obj2.cast(obj1)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast%28java.lang.Object%29), which casts `obj1` to the class or interface represented by `obj2`, returns `obj1` if `obj1` is assignable to the type `T` (note that `null` is assignable to any type), and throws `ClassCastException` otherwise.

We are not interested in the *result* of the cast, because the statically known type of `obj1` is already `T` and `obj2.cast(obj1)==obj1` (if the cast succeeds).  However, if the cast fails, an early exception will be thrown.

Example:

```
public <T> void readData(T obj1, Class<T> obj2){
 obj2.cast(obj1); 
 //... 
}
```

The following invocation (where there is an unchecked cast from `Class<?>` to `Class<String>`) will fail:

```
readData("Hello",(Class<String>)(Class<?>)Integer.class);
```

The method `cast` is also useful for replacing unchecked casts, for instance:

```
public <T> void readData(Object obj1, Class<T> obj2){
 T t = (T)obj1;//BAD: unchecked cast
 //...
}


public <T> void readData(Object obj1, Class<T> obj2){
 T t = obj2.cast(obj1());//GOOD: ClassCastException if the cast fails
 //...
}
```